# How to clear formatting while editing someone's post?

Tags: support, code-formatting, information-display

I have faced difficulties many times editing people's posts on Stack Overflow where I was trying to reformat improperly formatted code and other stuff. Is there a way of clearing previously done formatting and do it from scratch?

It seems easy sometimes if the formatting done by the user is messy.

Comment: Do you mean reverting your own changes or stripping *all* [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original formatting, as posted by the original poster, is available by clicking the link "edited Mon X 'YY at HH:MM" link above the most recent editor's avatar & name. This brings up all of the revisions made. From there the original source question - including code - can be copied.

Here is an example history for a question, showing revisions/edits:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3202567/revisions

For each revision there, there's a `source` button for copying original text (without the strike-through for deleted text).

Answer (score 3):

The code formatting facility in the Markdown editor is pretty basic... all it does is indent the code four spaces, or de-indent it if the smallest indent is four spaces.  It doesn't have any knowledge or awareness of code structure, so I doubt that it is going to be any help to you in that regard.

Your best bet is to selectively de-indent specific parts of the code code until it is at the correct indentation level, and work from there.